# Proofs that the sine function is strictly increasing on $[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, trigonometry

Here on the forum there are some proofs that the sine function is strictly increasing on $[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$, but they all use the fact that $\sin '(x)=\cos(x)$. Is there any rigorous proof without going through the derivative?

(Define $\sin$ like a ratio between sides of a right triangle)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: However you proceed will depend on how you [define](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sine_and_cosine#Definitions) sine.

Comment: We can use slope...

Comment: @user170231 Define in the form, given an angle of amplitude $\alpha$, the sine of this angle what it is (a quotient of two lengths). Now, to get the sine of a number, just consider $x=\pi*\alpha/180$.

Comment: When I draw a circle, I note that it goes up from the bottom to the top.

Comment: I can't parse the phrase "the sine of this angle what it is"; your following parenthetical remark suggests that you're looking at the ratio between sides of a right triangle, but I can't tell for sure. Your last sentence suggests that you're converting between radians and degrees, but that shouldn't enter into it. You should be able to do this directly on $x$ in radians, without involving $\alpha$ in degrees.

Comment: @BrianTung Could you explain how?

Comment: You'd first have to clarify how you're defining sine. But if you're just doing the ratio of two sides, you should be able to follow @davidlowryduda's advice.

Comment: it's just the proportion of sides

Comment: Then follow @davidlowryduda's approach or An_Elephant's answer. You should be aware, though, that sine is not usually rigorously defined in that way, in part because it gets in the way of showing these things rigorously. Sides of a triangle only have positive lengths.

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $x,y∈[-π/2,π/2]$ such that $x>y$.

Then,

sin$x -$sin$y = 2 $sin$\frac{x-y}{2}$cos$\frac{x+y}{2}>0$

Thus , sin$x>$sin$y$ whenever $x>y$ in the given domain and sin$x$ is increasing.

Comment: How do you know that $2\sin((x-y)/2)\cos((x+y)/2)>0)$?

Comment: @CPMP: Because $\cos$ is always positive in that region, and $\sin$ is positive in the first quadrant (where we are because we've assumed $x > y$).

Comment: @BrianTung  This strongly depends on the properties of sine and cosine which are assumed to be known.

Comment: @user: I don't disagree, but OP isn't giving us much to work with in terms of their definitions of sine and, one presumes, cosine.